# An arbitrary collection of integration exercises

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

1) I got the $A=2$ and $B=-1$. I think I'm just having trouble with the integration part now.

> Evaluate the integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{x-6}{x^2-6x+8}\,dx.$$

2) For this one I got that $A=7$, $B=-1$, and $C=1$.
I put $\ln |x|^3 - \ln |x+1| + \ln|x-1| + C$ but I keep getting this wrong.

> Evaluate the integral. (Remember to use $|u|$ where appropriate. Use $C$ for the constant of integration.)
>   $$\int\frac{7x^2+2x-7}{x^3-x}\,dx$$

3) For this one I have $A=7$, $B=0$, $C=0$, and $D=9$.
I put $\ln\bigl(|x^2+1||x^2+5|\bigr)+C$

> $$\int\frac{7x^3+9x^2+35x+9}{(x^2+1)(x^2+5)}\,dx$$

4)I used long division and got $x+\frac{-36x+36}{x^2+36}$.
Again, I'm having a lot of trouble integrating.

> $$\int\frac{x^3+36}{x^2+36}\,dx$$

Comment: Please only post one question at a time. Also for your fourth question, you got [several responses here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523209/integrate-frac-x3-36-x2-36/523213#523213).

Comment: Here is one : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523253/integrate-frac-7x2-2x-7-x3-x-dx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $(1)$  as $x^2-6x+8=(x-4)(x-2)$

use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure) to write $$\frac{x-6}{x^2-6x+8}=\frac A{x-4}+\frac 
B{x-2}$$

Multiply either sides by $x^2-6x+8=(x-4)(x-2),$ to get $x-6=A(x-2)+B(x-4)=x(A+B)-(2A+4B)$

Compare the coefficient of $x$ and the constant to find $A,B$

The link to the solutions of $(2),(4)$ are given in the comment

For $(3),$

**Method** $1:$ By observation  $7x^3+9x^2+35x+9=7x(x^2+5)+9(x^2+1)$

$$\implies \frac{7x^3+9x^2+35x+9}{(x^2+1)(x^2+5)}=\frac{7x(x^2+5)+9(x^2+1)}{(x^2+1)(x^2+5)}=\frac{7x}{x^2+1}+\frac9{x^2+5}$$

For the first part, use $x^2+1=u$ and for the second $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac1a\arctan\frac xa$

**Method** $2:$ Using Partial Fraction Decomposition I think you have already used

$$\frac{7x^3+9x^2+35x+9}{(x^2+1)(x^2+5)}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+1}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+5}$$

Multiply either sides by $(x^2+1)(x^2+5)$ and compare the coefficients of the different powers namely, $3,2,1,0$ of $x$ to find $A,B,C,D$

Answer (score 1):

Notice

$$ \int \frac{(x - 6) dx}{x^2 - 6x +8} = \int \frac{d(x^2 - 6x +8)}{2(x^2 - 6x +8)} - \int \frac{3dx}{(x^2 - 6x +8)} = \frac{1}{2} \ln | (x^2 - 6x +8) | - \int \frac{3dx}{(x^2 - 6x +8)}$$

Now, to solve $ \int \frac{3dx}{(x^2 - 6x +8)} $, we use partial fractions trick,

$$ \int \frac{3dx}{(x^2 - 6x +8)} = \int \frac{3dx}{(x-4)(x-2)} = \int \frac{3dx}{2(x-4)} - \int \frac{3 dx}{2(x-2)} = \frac{3}{2} \ln|x-4| - \frac{3}{2} \ln |x-2| + CONSTANT$$